# Run SharePoint Timer jobs from PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, installation

We are currently moving from using stsadm to using PowerShell for our SharePoint install scripts.

We have not been able to find an equivilent to this:

```
stsadm -o -execadmsvcjobs
```

We have tried putting in a pause, but it varies how long the pause needs to be.

Is there an equivilent command in PowerShell, or could we run this command from PowerShell?

Comment: please qualify with both a specific sharpeoint (2003, 2007, 2010) version and powershell version (1.0, 2.0) to get a decent answer

Comment: @x0n Thanks for your comment, it is 2010, Powershell does not work with any other version of SharePoint. Not sure of the PowerShell version, it is the latest version you get with windows update.

Comment: PowerShell "works" with any version of sharepoint; what you mean is that there are specific microsoft-shipped cmdlets for 2010. I (and thousands of others) frequently script sharepoint 2003 and 2007 with powershell. It works because sharepoint (from 2003 on) has a .NET object model, and any app with a public OM can be scripted with powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up using this solution from Sohel's Blog

http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-deployment-powershell.html

Comment: timores is correct: start-spadminjob is equivalent of execadmsvcjobs

Comment: @x0n, Start-SPAdminJob, we get an error message that the timer job is running, so it will be run by the timer

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the `Start-SPAdminJob` cmdlet [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607833.aspx)

According to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621084.aspx), it is the equivalent of execadmsvcjobs.

Comment: It is worth noting that execadmsvcjobs executed synchronously (e.g. stsadm wouldn't exit until it finished), Start-SPAdminJob just kicks off the job and then returns - letting the job run in the background. If you need synchronous behavior you need to check the job status and wait on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication $url

Get-SPTimerJob | ?{$_.Name -match "VariationsCreateHierarchies"} | ?{$_.Parent -eq $wa} | Start-SPTimerJob
```

This snippet runs the Create Variations Hierarchies job for the the web application at $url